# Different result of operator precedence in Java and Python

Tags: java, python, javac, operator-precedence, operations

I notice that I have two different result when I compile this operation in java, and python.

```
10 / 3 + 2 * 4 / 3 - 3
```

result in java = 2.0
     in python = 3.0

I also execute this operation in many calculators and the result is 3.0 can anyone explain how java deal with this?

```
double var = 10/3+2*4/3-3;
System.out.println(var);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression components will be evaluated as integers, i.e. intermediate values are truncated (`10/3` evaluates to `3`, `2*4/3` evaluates to `2` and so on).

Changing to the below will result in `3.0`:

```
double var = 10.0 / 3.0 + 2.0 * 4.0 / 3.0 - 3.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

In java :

```
10 / 3 + 2 * 4 / 3 - 3
(10 / 3) + (2 * (4 / 3))) - 3
3 + (2 * 1) - 3
3 + 2 - 3
2
```

Everything is cast to int, that why it's giving  this result.

Comment: There is no casting here.  It is simply integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Java follows a different order or operators than python:

Java : PMDRAS - parenthesis, multiplication, division , remainder, addition , subtraction.

Python : PEMDAS - Parenthesis, exponent , multiplication , division , addition , subtraction.

Comment: Since the operators that are different between the two languages are not present in the OP's question, how does this help?